# printing priority and resolution in jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

I need to print only priority and resolution and the records  $startAt =0 to &maxResults=1000. I see that this can't be archived by executing query anyone please help me attaching the code'

```
from Atlassian import Jira

Jira = Jira(

    url='http://localhost:8080',

    username='admin',

    password='admin')

JQL = 'project = DEMO AND status IN ("To Do", "In Progress") ORDER BY issuekey'

data = Jira.jql(JQL)

print(data)
```